# Select option default based on database variable

Tags: html, html-select

I have a form, with a simple select box, and I also have a text field that pulls a value. I want to use the value in `$Defaultselection` as the default value for the select options. So that if `$Defaultselection` = 4 then the default selected option would be D.

Using PHP/HTML

```
`$Defaultselection`
```

contains an integer between 1-4.

```
<select >
    <option value="1">A</option>
    <option value="2">B</option>
    <option value="3">C</option>
    <option value="4">D</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Please put your question with clearance

Comment: In which language do you want?

Comment: The page is a mix of html/php @PrashantParekh

Comment: yes that I understand, But I am not getting what you want to do with this?

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully better

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should do it:

```
<select >
    <option value="1" <?php echo ($Defaultselection == 1)?"selected":""; ?>>A</option>
    <option value="2" <?php echo ($Defaultselection == 2)?"selected":""; ?>>B</option>
    <option value="3" <?php echo ($Defaultselection == 3)?"selected":""; ?>>C</option>
    <option value="4" <?php echo ($Defaultselection == 4)?"selected":""; ?>>D</option>
</select>
```

or this other one:

```
<select >
    <option value="1" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 1) echo "selected"; ?>>A</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 2) echo "selected"; ?>>B</option>
    <option value="3" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 3) echo "selected"; ?>>C</option>
    <option value="4" <?php if ($Defaultselection == 4) echo "selected"; ?>>D</option>
</select>
```